# java helper class for merging/filling elements in list

Tags: java, list, mapping

This is a common pattern in our codebase, when mapping lists of models from (for example) Thing to MyModel:

```
List<MyModel> myModelList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Thing thing : things) {
    MyModel myModel = new MyModel(thing.getId());
    if (myModelList.contains(myModel)) {
        myModel = myModelList.get(myModelList.indexOf(myModel));
    } else {
        myModel.setName(thing.getName());
        myModelList.add(myModel);
    }
    myModel.setSomeQuantity(myModel.getSomeQuantity() + thing.getSomeQuantity());
}
```

(given that MyModel has equals() and hashCode() that uses id to decide on equality)

This could be done in some different ways, you could use a map with id as key etc. And we could make a general helper class for it that is used everywhere.

But what I'm wondering is if there already is some helper class or other kind of construct that takes care of all of this already, in an effective and clean way, in some java, apache, spring, google or other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both `contains` and `indexOf` on a `List`. Both of these generally require a linear search, so should be avoided if possible. You should definitely never use `indexOf` straight after `contains` like that. You never need to do this

```
if (list.contains(x)) 
    x = list.get(list.indexOf(x));
```

because you can always do this instead

```
int index = list.indexOf(x);
if (index >= 0)
    x = list.get(index);
```

This is more code, but avoids searching the list twice.

However, I dislike your use `equals` and `hashCode`. Normally, `equal` objects can be treated interchangeably, whereas in your case, the two versions of `myModel` are not the same; only the one already in the list carries the extra information about the name and the total quantity.

I would suggest replacing `MyModel` with an immutable class `MyModel` with only two fields (`id` and `name`). Then you could do this (assuming you are using Java 8)

```
Map<MyModel, Double> quantities = new HashMap<>();
for (Thing thing : things)
    quantities.merge(thing.getModel(), thing.getQuantity(), Double::sum);
```

Comment: Great answer! We can't use java 8 yet, but soon, so I'll start using this pattern when we're there. :)

Comment: @TV'sFrank I program in android, so can't use java 8 either. I find `Map.merge` so useful I've written a static method for it.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a job for a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) than a List.

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element.

```
Set<MyModel> myModelSet = new HashSet<>();
for (Thing thing : things) {
    MyModel myModel = new MyModel(thing.getId());
    myModel.setName(thing.getName());
    // copy more fields if nessecary or write a copyFromThing() method  or a constructor that accepts Thing as a parameter in the MyModel class

    myModel.setSomeQuantity(myModel.getSomeQuantity() + thing.getSomeQuantity());
    myModelSet.add(myModel);
}
```

EDIT: problem is, that Set does not have a `get` method which will be a problem, when MyModel has more fields to copy